# Escribir diccionario de diccionarios a CSV con el formato key,key,value en cada fila

Tags: python, csv, dict, dictwriter

Tengo el siguiente diccionario de diccionarios.

```
{'Spain': {'Barcelona': '20', 'Madrid': '17', 'Sevilla': '25'}, 'France': {'Paris': '18', 'Toulose': '15'}}
```

Me gustaría generar un csv donde en cada fila aparezca el key del diccionario y sus valores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy probando de readaptar el código de otra [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373247/how-do-i-write-a-python-dictionary-to-a-csv-file) pero no lo consigo :

```
import csv

my_dict = {"test": 1, "testing": 2}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # You will need 'wb' mode in Python 2.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas ningún módulo especial para algo tan sencillo. Es conveniente que aprendas a hacerlo con herramientas simples, que es más versátil. Por ejemplo, puedes adaptar este mismo código para calcular la temperatura promedio por país fácilmente.

```
dic = {'Spain': {'Barcelona': '20', 'Madrid': '17', 'Sevilla': '25'}, 'France': {'Paris': '18', 'Toulose': '15'}}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    for pais, ciudades in dic.items():
        for ciudad in ciudades:
            temp = dic[pais][ciudad]
            f.write(f"{pais}, {ciudad}, {temp}\n")
```

Tenemos un primer `for` que extrae cada país con sus ciudades. El segundo `for` recorre las ciudades de ese país, extrayendo la temperatura de cada una.

El archivo se genera con un simple write, usando `f" "` para producir cada linea:

```
Spain, Barcelona, 20
Spain, Madrid, 17
Spain, Sevilla, 25
France, Paris, 18
France, Toulose, 15
```

Comment: Gracias @Candid Moe . He añadido las cabeceras antes del for `f.write("Country,City,Temperature,\n")`

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictWriter` no te es de mucha ayuda aquí porque tu diccionario no tiene las cabeceras como claves. Si quieres usar el módulo `csv`, lo que es recomendable para evitar problemas de formato, acotado..., es más simple usar `csv.writer` en este caso:

```
import csv


my_dict = {
    'Spain': {
        'Barcelona': '20',
        'Madrid': '17',
        'Sevilla': '25'},
    'France': {
        'Paris': '18',
        'Toulose': '15'}
}

header = ("Country", "City", "Temperature")
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(header)
    for country, cities in my_dict.items():
        for city, temp in cities.items():
            writer.writerow((country, city, temp))
```

Siempre se debe especificar la codificación a usar a `open`, en caso contrario esta será dependiente de la plataforma y es una de las fuentes más comunes de errores posteriormente.